# Why can't character constants/literals be empty?

Tags: c++, c, character

In C and C++ the rules are the same. In C,

> `[§6.4.4.4]/2` An integer character constant is a sequence of one or
>   more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`.

In C++,

> `[§2.14.3]/1` A character literal is one or more characters enclosed
>   in single quotes, as in `'x'`, optionally preceded by one of the
>   letters `u`, `U`, or `L`, as in `u'y'`, `U'z'`, or `L'x'`,
>   respectively.

The key phrase is "one or more". In contrast, a string literal can be empty, `""`, presumably because it consists of the null terminating character. In C, this leads to awkward initialization of a char. Either you leave it uninitialized, or use a useless value like `0` or `'\0'`.

```
char garbage;
char useless = 0;
char useless2 = '\0';
```

In C++, you have to use a string literal instead of a character literal if you want it to be empty.

```
(somecondition ? ' ' : '') // error
(somecondition ? " " : "") // necessary
```

What is the reason it is this way? I'm assuming C++'s reason is inherited from C.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is that a character literal is defined as a character. There may be extensions that allow it to be *more* than one character, but it needs to be at least one character or it just doesn't make any sense. It would be the same as trying to do:

```
int i = ;
```

If you don't specify a value, what do you put there?

Comment: There's no need for any extension. Multi-character literals are very much standard, they're just not very useful because their value is implementation defined.

Answer (score 3):

This is because an empty string still contains the the null character `'\0'` at the end, so there is still a value to bind to the variable name, whereas an empty character literal has no value.

Answer (score 0):

String is a set of character terminated by a NULL character ( '\0' ). 
So a Empty string will always have a NULL character in it at the end .

But in case of a character literal no value is there.
it needs at least  one character.